# Expected number of turns until Loss, modified Gamblers Ruin

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, expected-value, markov-chains, gambling

Consider a modified gamblers ruin Markov Chain on the set of natural numbers {0,1,2,3...}.
We start in state 1, and at each turn, for state i, we have a probability p to go to state i+1, and a probability q to go to state 0. Meaning that in this modification losing once means going bankrupt immediately, regardless of current state. I am interested in getting an expression for the Expected number of turns to hit state 0, starting at state 1. I tried using splitting and then ended up with a recurrence relationship I though I can solve k(i)=p*k(i+1) + 1, with k(0)=0, but the answers I get don't seem to make any sense (after trying special case p=q=1/2, the expectations are negative).

Could anyone please suggest an approach for solving this problem?
Thank you very much, and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: Thank you very much, for some reason I did not see this was just a geometric distribution…